# PHP Code in Smarty - Urlencode

Tags: php, smarty

I have a part of Code mixed with PHP and Smarty. How can I write all Code in Smarty?

```
{php}$shortenedurl = file_get_contents('http://url.to/api.php?url=' . urlencode({$ShopURL}/index.php?wlid={$CWunschliste->cURLID});{/php}

<input type="text" id="wunschliste_public_url" value="{php}echo $shortenedurl;{/php}" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fetch the file contents outside the template and pass it in?

Comment: The Problem is how can I call the smarty code outside? `{$ShopURL}/index.php?wlid={$CWunschliste->cURLID}` because I just can call it inside the smarty template

Comment: What Smarty code? All I see are variables that are passed to the template. Surely you have access to those outside the template?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Smarty this way. You should do such operations in PHP and assign Smarty variables. Smarty are template engine and you should only display data using it. If you use template engine (Smarty or any other) it in that way there's no point to use it at all. It's only affects your performance and doesn't give you any benefits.